# unknown attribute 'avatar' for Profile. Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, user-profile

When I run migration,

this got created:

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   change_table :profiles do |t|
   t.attachment :avatar
  end
end

 def self.down
   remove_attachment :profiles, :avatar
 end
end
```

then added:

```
<%= f.label :avatar %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

to views.
When I upload to create a profile I get an error (in title).

I have this def in my `profiles_controller`:

```
private
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :avatar, :phone_number, :contact_email, :description)
end
```

I have added the following in my `application_controller` too:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) << :avatar
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:avatar) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:avatar) }  
end
```

And `users_controller`:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:avatar)
end
```

Still getting an error after this.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
["id", "user_id", "first_name", "last_name", "phone_number", 
"contact_email", "description", "avatar_file_name", 
"avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_size", "avatar_updated_at"]
```

@Pavan - I did run migrate

UPDATE:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: 
  "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: 
  /\Aimage\/.*\z/
 end
end
```

Comment: Do `Profile.column_names` in the console and paste the result here

Comment: Hold on, did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Can you update the question with Profile model

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why do you have a User class inside a Profile class. Remove it and keep `has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: 
  "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: 
  /\Aimage\/.*\z/`

Comment: @Pavan thanks very much. worked now, after removing the User class.

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unknown attribute 'avatar' for Profile

The problem is with your `Profile` model having a `User` model inside it. You should remove the `User` model and keep the rest.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: 
  "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: 
  /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this @Pavan